# Using external config file for UrlRewriter.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I'm using the [UrlRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net) library to implement url rewriting for my asp.net website. The rewriting rules are currently being read from the `web.config` file like this

```xml
<rewriter>
  <rewrite url="/test-web-page" to="~/realwebpage.aspx"/>
</rewriter>
```

How do I make the library read my rewriting rules from another file rather than the `web.config`?

Comment: Why do you want to read the rewriting rules from a different file?

Comment: Hi sbhomra, because I'm afraid if I add too many rules inside, problems may appear so I put them in a separate file, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can - it is mentioned here on this page http://urlrewriter.net/ interesting looking at their examples the do not specify exactly hw to do it. But I did some digging on their support forum and found this example:

```
<rewriter configSource="YOURREWRITEFILE"> 
    </rewriter>
```

Full dialogue can be read here:

[https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/UrlRewriter/external$20config/urlrewriter/TgKVlJ9bO_s/CgtEEpcMIrkJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/UrlRewriter/external%2420config/urlrewriter/TgKVlJ9bO_s/CgtEEpcMIrkJ)